# Why don't we say "contrast" rather than "compare"?

Tags: vocabulary

I am wondering if it is not more proper to say *contrast* than *compare*:

used to **compare** two aspects of a situation Stress can be extremely damaging to your health. Exercise, meanwhile, can reduce its effects.

[enter link description here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/meanwhile_1)

Comment: It depends on whether you are interested in pointing out the similarities or the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either contrast or compare here, but there will be some difference in meaning.

If you want to examine how two things are similar and different, you can use the verb compare.

However, if you want to examine only how two things are different, you can use contrast.